# Remove power off menu Ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell

I'm trying to remove the top rigth menu with sound volum, ethernet connexion, account setting and power off button without install too much extension and with command line (gsetting)

[image: this menu]

Answer (score 0):

You appear to object against installing extensions, but if one existed, that would be the easiest approach. Your alternative probably is editing .css source code yourself, or, worse, editing source code and recompiling.

For sure, this is not controlled by any gsetting. I am not aware of an extension that removes the "Status menu". there are extensions that break the single button into separate buttons for the different functions (e.g. different two extensions each called "Alternative status menu", or "Extend panel men"), but these do not appear to be maintained anymore.

So unless I stand corrected by other answers, there appears to be no way to remove that menu apart from editing source code.

Comment: Thanks, I played a little with CSS in /usr/share/gnome-shell/them/ubuntu.css but I couldn't find the menu selector on the top right. I found GtkInspector but couldn't find how to use it for the interface.